# API design - indicate that results were truncated

Tags: rest, api, api-design, http

For *reasons*, my search endpoint returns a maximum of 50 results.

I'm struggling with how best to tell the caller that their results were limited to 50.

The best I've come up with is returning some additional fields:

```
{
    results: [
        ...
    ],
    resultsTruncated: true,
    resultsReturned: 50,
    totalMatchingResults: 1232
}
```

Is there a better option?

I was really hoping for a 2xx response code, but none seem appropriate.

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel. Use pagination.

Comment: @Laiv I would love to, but it wouldn't fit the business need.  The search is returning sensitive data.  So the caller isn't allowed to browse through pages of results.  They should be able to find what they're looking for within 50, or supply better search parameters.

Comment: then the client doesn't need to know the result is truncated. Devs might need it, client surely doesn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Useful heuristic: how would you do it with web pages?

> The best I've come up with is returning some additional fields

Extending your representation to include additional information for the client is an appropriate way to do that.

This is, after all, exactly what you would do if you were returning a bunch of results in an HTML document.

> I was really hoping for a 2xx response code, but none seem appropriate.

None of them are.

Basically, what you have here is a "page" resource -- you are returning a complete representation of a cropped view of your data.

**Edit**: notes on using standard [pagination](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5005#section-3) and [search offsets](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/guides/working-with-timelines.html) removed because they aren't compatible with "the caller isn't allowed to browse through pages of results".

Answer (score 1):

If it really is hardcoded to maximum of 50 rather than being a pagination thing then maybe you don't need to do anything. Just update the documentation and return an array of results and stop when you get to 50.

The way I've seen it done is the same way you suggest. Return a "SearchResult" which contains the extra meta information